# how to change background color of my website on an interval

Tags: javascript, html, css

Today I visited [this](http://www.noisli.com/) site and it looked awesome the feature of changing background color with respect to time i tried searching for `changebackground()` but could not find it can you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried inspecting and find the function on console but it returned an error

Comment: I think @Dude is asking what code you have tried. Also google is a good friend

Comment: You want to shot a guess that the site has a function `changebackgorund`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This my be what you are looking for:**

```
<style>
body {
    background: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(145, 207, 161);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    transition: all 10s ease-in-out;
}

* {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
</style><script type="text/javascript">
function cb()
{
var c = "#1abc9c #2ecc71 #3498db #ea5b4d #9b59b6 #34495e #16a085 #27ae60 #2980b9 #8e44ad #2c3e50 #f1c40f #e67e22 #e74c3c #f39c12 #d35400 #c0392b #06b3db #4ed486 #6139f6 #e3b63d #dc3d66 #bd3559 #bd54cd #0082c8 #16528e #e54b4b #a2c5bf #167c80 #72616e #e8846b #ea5b4d #72BDC2".split(" ");
var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * c.length); 
d = c[d];
document.body.style.background=d;
setTimeout("cb()",1000);}
</script>
<body onload="cb()">
```

Answer (score 3):

on each interval call.

```
setInterval(intr,2000);

function intr()
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor="#colorInHex";
}
```

Note I've edited this post to call the interval function by reference. See the evils of eval by douglas crockford for fuller explanation.

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setInterval`!  That uses `eval`, which is a bad practice to use.  Pass a function: `setInterval(intr, 2000);`

Answer (score 2):

## CSS Animation:

CSS Animation is [currently supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) on all browsers except Opera Mini. It takes advantage of hardware acceleration and is preferred to JavaScript animations.  In fact, jQuery animations try to use CSS3 animations and fall back to JS if the browser doesn't support it.

You can literally take this code and drop it in. See the [FIDDLE here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZH8GN/).

```
body {
  animation: colorchange 50s; /* animation-name followed by duration in seconds*/
     /* you could also use milliseconds (ms) or something like 2.5s */
  -webkit-animation: colorchange 50s; /* Chrome and Safari */
}

@keyframes colorchange
{
  0%   {background: red;}
  25%  {background: yellow;}
  50%  {background: blue;}
  75%  {background: green;}
  100% {background: red;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorchange /* Safari and Chrome - necessary duplicate */
{
  0%   {background: red;}
  25%  {background: yellow;}
  50%  {background: blue;}
  75%  {background: green;}
  100% {background: red;}
}
```

The site you referenced uses 10 second transitions, so I took the number of colors (5) and multiplied that by 10 seconds to arrive at an animation duration of 50s.

Then you take the number of steps or colors (5) minus 1 (for the 0%), so now 4, and divide 100 by it, so 25.  This gives you your step distance, so 5 steps from 0-100%: 0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%.

Since the request is pretty simple, I just used the color names. They are not specific and are open to browser/OS interpretation. If you want more specific colors, you can use [this color generator](http://www.standardista.com/hsla-color-picker/) and replace the color names with one of these values.

### Original Answer:

## CSS Transitions:

This site uses CSS transitions.  There is a declaration of:

```
* {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
```

Then you define some color classes like:

```
.green {
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
}
.red {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
.blue {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}
```

Then you set different classes on the body tag, and that will cause the transition like that, because of the transition CSS you defined initially

EDIT: I misspoke, slightly. here is the ACTUAL transition on the body tag:

```
transition: all 10s ease-in-out;
```

Of course, the CSS colors on the body are being set with JS on a timer, but it's a trivial operation and the CSS does the bulk of the work, and you can do it more elegantly by simply setting classes than by setting the bg color directly with script.

Comment: nice one, and the only css solution in here :D

Comment: haha I pretty much literally ripped it straight from their site ;)  But it works! :) Thanks!

Comment: you can eliminate need of js from code by adding css animation

Comment: can you please give me full code I am a newbie and unable to implement.

Comment: Ah, sure. Let me see if I can get a fiddle going.

Comment: There you go! Hope it helps ya out. I think the Fiddle is effective. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


/* Method To Generate Random Numbers Between "0-255" for RGB Color-code Format & Assign To Body-Backgrond-Style */

function bgDisco()
{
var  x =Math.round(255*Math.random());

var num1 =getHex(x);

var  y =Math.round(255*Math.random());

var num2 =getHex(y);

var  z =Math.round(255*Math.random());

var num3 =getHex(z);

document.body.style.background="#"+num1+num2+num3;

setTimeout("bgDisco",1000);
}

/* Method To Convert  Decimal To Hexadecimal */

function getHex(dec)
{
var hexArray = new Array( "0", "1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6", "7","8", "9", "A", "B","C", "D", "E", "F" );

var code1 = Math.floor(dec / 16);

var code2 = dec - code1 * 16;

var decToHex = hexArray[code2];

return (decToHex);
}
</script>
</head>
```

Now on the body part call the "bgDisco()" in onload event.

```
<body onload="bgDisco()">
```

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`!  That uses `eval`, which is a bad practice to use.  Pass a function: `setTimeout(bgDisco, 1000);`

Comment: Can i make the changes in an smooth way..

Comment: @RocketHazmat canyou help me in this??

Comment: @Amarnath: Help you with what?

Comment: @baibavkumar hey carry on if it helps some one im very glad about it..!!

Comment: @RocketHazmat setTimeout(bgDisco,1000) ???

Comment: @Amarnath: What about it?  In your code you had `setTimeout("bgDisco()",1000);`, which is *bad practice*.  The line I provided should be used instead.

Comment: @RocketHazmat may i know what changes should i do??

Comment: @Amarnath: Replace `setTimeout("bgDisco()",1000)` with `setTimeout(bgDisco, 1000);`.

Comment: The color changes in a sudden can i use it with css like `-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;`

Comment: I mean a color fades to another slowly

Comment: please to be seeing my answer, it describes how the transitions occur.

Comment: @baibavkumar give it a try..!!

Comment: I tried but it looks very odd when background color changes on a sudden.

Comment: @baibavkumar this needs CSS transitions to get the fade effect. Please see my answer for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code of the page, you will see this:

```
<body onload="prettyPrint(); changebackground();" id="main">
```

I will dig up an I will post here the changebackground() function. I think that's you want.

Comment: Yes please it will be great ..

Comment: @Dude, if you could find where is the definition of the changebackground() function, I will delete my post and I will upvote yours. I don't think so that you will find it quite easily. Also, if you have something that will help baibav post it, like the other dudes above.